# How to authenticate a Linux User against Oracle Windows NTS?

Tags: authentication, oracle

We are using NTS for our Oracle Windows on a Windows Server 2016. Adding domain users to the ora_dba group works if we want to connect remotely as System Administrator.

But is it possible to authenticate a Linux user as an administrator against that Windows Oracle Installation? The Linux users are not part of the AD Domain, so I can't add them to the ora_dba group...

Comment: you can join the Linux server to the AD domain.

Comment: Ow man... That'll be something for our IT department to do. Isn't there any other way?